# Get list of all tags name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to simply get a list of all html tags that browser recognizes using javascript in preferably an array.

I know you can get all css properties using this:

```
Object.keys(getComputedStyle(document.body))
```

Comment: or list of all nodeName is fine too

Comment: `document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");` ?

Comment: this will give all tags only present in the page, not all tags recognized by browser

Comment: Do you need a full list? Or would being able to test if a given element name is recognized suffice?

Comment: A full list if possible